# Non-Prime Number Counter in C

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I want to write a program for storing all the non-prime(composite) numbers before 10.000 in an array. I did this algorithm below, but it's not working. When I print out the array which is supposed to be holding composite numbers, it's simply counting from 4 to 10.000 .

Where is the problem? I really looked so much but I can't see.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10000

void compositeChecker(int[]);

int main() {
    int k;
    int compositeArray[SIZE]= {0};
    compositeChecker(compositeArray);
    for(k=0; k<100; k++) {
        printf("%d\n",compositeArray[k]);
    }
}

void compositeChecker(int arr[]) {
    int i,j,counter=0;

    for(i=4; i<10000; i++) {
        for(j=2; j<i; j++) {
            if((i%j)==0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter!=0) {
            arr[i-4]=i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a debugger and step through your program.

Comment: Given that in the first loop iteration `i == 4`, you increment `counter`, hence `counter` is never ever `0` again, you are just filling `arr` with consecutive values of `i`.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because of the logic in your code.  Inside of your `for` loop, you say this:

```
for(j=2;j<i;j++) {
 if((i%j)==0){

    counter++;

 }    
}

if(counter!=0){

    arr[i-4]=i;
}
```

So, once you find any composite number, you increment counter.  Counter is never reset to zero in your loop, so every single number is added to your array.  Even if your logic were fixed, you would be adding values to an array in a way that doesn't make sense.  Consider the values 5 and 6.

Even if you corrected the logic, 5 would not be added... So `arr[i-4]` (arr[1]) would have no value... but when I=6, `arr[i-4]` would have a value.  You probably want to change this logic to count how many composite numbers you have found so far and add the number found to the array at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is clearly not resetting `counter` as @DavidHoelzer points out.  But there's another bug as simply fixing `counter` leaves zeros in your output where the primes were.

I believe the real fix is to eliminate `counter` as it's wrongheaded.  Once you determine a number is composite, you keep checking more divisors but ignore all that extra work when you test `if (counter != 0)`. So, we should just make a note once we find the first divisor and move onto the next number.  This is a perfect use of a `break` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 100

void compositeChecker(bool array[]) {

    for (int i = 3; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                array[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    bool compositeArray[SIZE] = {false};

    compositeChecker(compositeArray);

    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
        if (compositeArray[k]) {
                printf("%d\n", k);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also changed `compositeArray` not to be a list of composite numbers but rather a list of booleans indicating whether a particular index is composite or not.

A final issue is one of terminology.  Your code is looking for ***composite*** numbers but your title and text say ***non-prime***.  The difference is how you handle 0 and 1.  If you're looking for composite numbers, exclude them.  If you're looking for non-prime numbers, include them.

Answer (score 0):

Composite numbers is non-prime numbers greater than 1. So all you have to do is to find prime number up to 10k. It can easily be done by **erythrophene sieve**.

[The principle of the sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V08g_lkKj6Q)

Create array which maps numbers to {1, 0}, 1 - if number is prime, 0 - if composite.

```
#define SIZE 10001
int is_prime[10000];
```

Now let's initialize sieve:

```
void init_sieve()
{
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i )
        is_prime[i] = 1;

    is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = 0;

    for( i = 2; i < SIZE; ++i )
        if( is_prime[i] )
            for( j = i*i; j < SIZE; j += i )
                is_prime[j] = 0;
}
```

So we got bool array, each element of which is 1 if element's index is prime, 0 otherwise.
Now, we can simple iterate throw it and get composite numbers.

```
for( int i = 4; i < SIZE; ++i )
    if( !is_prime[i] )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", i );
    }
```

First 10 number from stdout:
    4
    6
    8
    9
    10
    12
    14
    15
    16
    18
    20
    21
    22
    24
    25
    26
    27
    ...